# Can Boost Date Time Input/Output parse a date with an ordinal day of the month, like "January 2nd, 2024"?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I am using a library which delegates date formatting to [Boost Date Time Input/Output](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html), and i need to parse dates which look like "January 2nd, 2024".

The month and the year are easy enough, as are the spaces and comma.

The format specifier `%e` parses a day of the month, and copes with one or two digits, without requiring a leading zero or space. But it will apparently not trailing ordinal characters. I tried parsing the string

```
January 2nd, 2024
```

Using:

```
%B %e, %Y
```

And it comes out with a gibberish value.

Is there a way to parse dates like this? I would happily ignore the exact characters in the ordinal suffix, and so treat strings like:

```
January 2th, 2024
```

As valid.

Comment: would you share the exact code you are using?

Comment: @Kelsey I am using some obscure library which uses Boost for parsing, so my actual code will not be at all helpful. Date strings and format strings are passed straight through.

Comment: unless we know which module you're using via Boost for parsing, we can't really help unfortunately

Comment: doesn't look like it: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags, you could preprocess the string with a regex to remove the suffixes

Comment: @Kelsey As stated in the title, [Boost Date Time Input/Output](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html) - i will edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I'd appreciate if you could post that as a simple answer. That way, people can stop the reflexive downvoting that tends to happen because more people keep vetting unanswered questions.